# How to get the last 5 images uploaded from parse.com?

Tags: android, image, parse-platform, picasso

I am developing an app to query images(uploaded from my raspberryPI) from parse.com. I am also using Picasso to display the image. My raspberrypi is programmed to take 5 pictures at an hourly interval. I want to retrieve only the latest 5 images that were uploaded to parse. My code is:

```
ParseObject object = mImages.get(position);
//get the image

Picasso.with(getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(object.getParseFile("pictures")
            .getUrl()).noFade().into(holder.homeImage);

return convertView;
```

I am not too sure how to modify the code to retrieve only the latest 5 images. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

P.S. I am new to andriod ,parse and stackoverflow. Nice to meet you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code for fetching the last 5 images. A little explanation of this code is added at the end.

```
List<ParseObject> objects;
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("YourClassName");
query.setLimit(5);
query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
try {
    objects = query.find();
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++)   {

        ParseFile file = objects.get(i).getParseFile("pictures");
        file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
                if (bytes != null && e == null) {
                    Bitmap bmpImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                } else {
                    // DO SOMETHING HERE
                }
            }
        });
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**The explanation:**

1. Replace the `YourClassName` with the class name from where you are going to query the images.
2. The `query.orderByDescending("createdAt");` along with `query.setLimit(5);` ensures that only the last 5 images are retrieved from Parse.
3. This code does not account for the use of Picasso. This example however, converts the retrieved `ParseFile` into a `Bitmap`. Setting that to an `ImageView`, for instance, is straightforward enough.
4. This code is used in an `Asynctask` and therefore does not use the `query.findInBackground(...)`. Do modify as necessary.

Comment: Hi, your code imagesQuery.setLimit(5) is working. But imagesQuery.orderByDescending("createdAT"); and query.orderByDescending("createdAt") isn't. Am i missing something? I checked my parse.com date column and it's name createdAt.

Comment: @Hilda: Update your OP with the new code and let me see if I can help sort it out.

Comment: Hey there, the code somehow worked. Maybe I made a typo somewhere. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Hilda: Ah. That is awesome. Was is it the capital **T** in `imagesQuery.orderByDescending("createdAT")` that proved to be the problem? In any case, I am glad I could have been of help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the complete `list` from the following code and then get the last five from `arraylist`

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(YourModel.class.getSimpleName());
        query.whereContains("key", "value");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                  // fetch the last five objects from this list
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

ParseQuery will hopefully solve your problem

```
ParseQuery parseQuery = new ParseQuery("pictures");
parseQuery.setLimit(5);
parseQuery.findInBackground(your_method_name);
```